# dynamically allocate string using malloc

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am new to C programming. Right now I am learning string and pointers.
As a beginner I find it difficult to find the mistake. I have written a code for dynamic allocation of a string and print the string using function.the code is given below.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 void fun (char *);

 int main()
 {
    int n;
    char *s = NULL;
    printf("enter the length of the string\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s  = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    printf("enter the string\n");
    fgets(s, 20, stdin);
    printf("string before  passing is %s\n",s);
    fun(s);
    return 0;
 }

 void fun( char *p)
 {
    char *d;
    d = p;
    printf("string after passing is%s\n",d);      
 }
```

There is no error message while compiling. But the code doesn't take string.
Can anyone please help me in finding the mistake.

Comment: learn how to use debugger.

Comment: can u please help me how to use it?

Comment: What's your sample input and the output?

Comment: `fgets(s, 20, stdin);` ---> `fgets(s, n, stdin);`

Comment: when il give the length of the string and after pressing enter .i am not able to enter the string.finally my output is like just "string before passing " and "string after passing".i am not able to iput the string.

Comment: also, be wary of the string you created. i noticed you didn't allocate for or append a NULL terminator `\0`, so your `printf` could overrun... see `printf( "%*s", len, str)`...

Comment: @ matt i did the same.but still the same output

Comment: nothing concern to length. Yes, output is danger, but problem is in buffering

Comment: @polarysekt the `fgets` function always appends a null terminator (unless `n < 1`)

Comment: aye. I perhaps eyed this a little too quickly. Does the `malloc` still suffice?

Comment: This issue (read with `%d` leaves newline in buffer) seems to come up many times a week but I don't see a canonical duplicate

Comment: I found the answer to my own question... "until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first" and "A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have five major bugs in your code.

1. `scanf` will not "consume" the newline generated when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, so you'll need `getchar` to follow it to handle this unexpected behavior.
2. You're not checking the result of `malloc`. It is possible for this function to fail.
3. `fgets` should use `n` to determine the maximum amount of data to take from the user, or you'll generate a segmentation fault by overflowing your buffer.
4. The string containing the result of `fgets` ends with a newline character AND a NULL terminating character in typical cases. You can use `strtok` to replace the trailing newline with a NULL character to avoid unexpected behaviors.
5. You are not `free`ing the memory you created with `malloc`. This leads to memory leaks.

**EDIT**: Matt McNabb provides an alternative approach to handling the unconsumed `\n` in FIX1, which I think is a cleaner approach than mine.

The solution is posted below.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void fun (char *);

int main() {
   int n;
   char *s = NULL;
   printf("enter the length of the string\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   (void)getchar();     // FIX1

   s  = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
   if (s == NULL) {     // FIX2
      printf("malloc error; aborting\n");
      return 1;
   }
   printf("enter the string\n");
   fgets(s, n, stdin);  // FIX3
   strtok(s, "\n");     // FIX4
   printf("string before  passing is %s\n",s);
   fun(s);
   free(s);             // FIX5
   return 0;
}

void fun(char *p) {
   char *d;
   d = p;

   printf("string after passing is %s\n",d);
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
enter the length of the string
10
enter the string
This is a test for overflows.
string before  passing is This is a
string after passing is This is a
```

Comment: well, that's a novel use for `strtok`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. It's kind of like some of the neat "top 10" useful bit manipulation tricks in C; Fun to know.

Comment: Thanks.So whenever i use malloc i need to check the malloc and free the memory malloc has created right?Understood lot of things:)

Comment: @vipil Correct. You ALWAYS check if `malloc`/`calloc` succeeded (well, pretty much any function in general that returns an error code), and `free` anything allocated with `malloc`/`calloc`/`strdup`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

After you entered the number and press ENTER, the number assumed by this `scanf` line but the new line character is still in buffer. The next `fgets` line takes only that new line.

One simple way to fix the problem is:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
getchar();      //consume the new line
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `scanf("%d",&n);` , it extracts an integer from the stream. It does not discard the rest of the line. So if you typed a number and pressed enter, then the newline remains in the stream .

So when you do `fgets` it reads the rest of that line, which is blank.

To fix this you need to read up to the end of the line. One way to do that is:

```
int ch;
while ( (ch == getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ) { }
```

Then you can go on to do:

```
fgets(s, n, stdin);   // n, not 20
```

Also, you should check the result of malloc, e.g.

```
 s  = malloc(n);
 if ( s == NULL )
     return 0;   // or some other error handling
```

Casting malloc has been [a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) since 1989, but it's a matter of style whether you want to include the `sizeof(char)` or not, since `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

To be complete you could also check the result of `fgets`, for example if your input was closed then you would be outputting garbage.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void fun (char *);

int main()
{
        int n;
        char *s = NULL;
        char ch;

        /* Taking String length from the User */
        printf("enter the length of the string\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        /* Allocating Memory */
        s = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char));

        /* Checking for memory allocation */
        if (s == NULL)
        {
                printf("\n Error in allocating memory \n");
                exit(0);
        }

        /* Flush standard inputs */
        while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
        {
        }

        printf("enter the string\n");
        fgets(s, n+1, stdin);

        printf("string before  passing is %s\n",s);
        fun(s);

        /* Need to free the allocated memory */
        free(s);
        return 0;
}

void fun( char *p)
{
        char *d;
        d = p;
        printf("string after passing is %s \n",d);
}
```

Comment: `char ch;` --> `int ch;` , `fgets(s, n+1, stdin);` --> `fgets(s, n, stdin);`

Answer (score 0):

in short, fgets reads from buffer and buffer is already full. Solution is not to use fgets or flush buffer before reading

```
printf("enter the string\n");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(s, 20, stdin);
```

UPD

so if fflush is undefined for stdin, then flush it as Matt McNabb mentioned above

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Comment: `fflush` is for flushing output streams. Doing it on input streams causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: One does not simply flush `stdin`. C standard n1570 7.21.5.2 The `fflush` function, clause 2: _If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined._